# Simplify $\sqrt{a^6 + 2a^4b^2 + a^2b^4}$

Tags: absolute-value

Simplify $\sqrt{a^6 + 2a^4b^2 + a^2b^4}$ for $a < 0$

I've almost got it but I have a question about the answer. This is my solution:

$$\sqrt{a^6 + 2a^4b^2 + a^2b^4}$$
$$\sqrt{a^2 (a^4 + 2a^2b^2 + b^4)}$$
$$a \cdot \sqrt{a^4 + 2a^2b^2 + b^4}$$
$$a^2 = t$$
$$a \cdot \sqrt{t^2 + 2b^2t + b^4}$$
$$a \cdot \sqrt{(t+b^2)^2}$$
$$a \cdot |t+b^2|$$
$$a \cdot |a^2+b^2|$$

Now splitting the cases for when $a^2 + b^2 < 0$ **vs** $a^2 + b^2 > 0$ gives
$$a \cdot (a^2+b^2)$$
$$-a \cdot (a^2 + b^2)$$

Now, my textbook only gives the solution $$-a\cdot(a^2+b^2)$$
**Why?**

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. Now that $a<0$... You made a mistake when bringing out  $a^2$ from the square root. Line 3.

Comment: Because $a<0$, but $\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ for all real $x$

Comment: $a^2 + b^2$ is always greater than zero.  And $\sqrt {a^2} = |a|$  You should have $|a|(a^2+b^2)$ somewhere along the way.  Then evaluate what happens when $a<0$

Answer (score 2):

When you moved $a^2$ out from square root, you forgot to take absolute value:

$$\sqrt{a^2 \cdot (a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4)}=|a| \sqrt{a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4}$$

and since $a < 0$, we have $$|a| = -a$$

Answer (score 1):

since $a<0$ $$\sqrt { a^{ 6 }+2a^{ 4 }b^{ 2 }+a^{ 2 }b^{ 4 } } =\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }{ \left( { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\left| a\left( { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } \right)  \right| =\left| a \right| \left| \left( { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } \right)  \right| =-a\left( { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } \right) \\ $$

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$\sqrt{t^2}=|t|=t\quad\text{if $\ t\ge 0$}$$
$$\sqrt{t^2}=|t|=-t\quad\text{if $\ t\lt 0$}$$

In your case, 
$$\sqrt{a^6+2a^4b^2+a^2b^4}=\sqrt{a^2(a^2+b^2)^2}=\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^2}$$
which is equal to
$$-a(a^2+b^2)$$
since $a\lt 0$ and $a^2+b^2\gt 0$.